# How to run multiple Linux commands using java.lang.process?

Tags: java, process

I have an example like the below showed. The command

`iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p iscsiInfo.ipAddress`

will be executed here, what if I want to execute extra command after executing this, like

`ls /var/lib/iscsi/nodes`

how to do it using java.lang.process?

Add, I only need to execute the 1st command, but I need to get the 2nd command results and show it in GUI.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
       String line;
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p iscsiInfo.ipAddress");
       BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
       BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
       while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }
       bri.close();
       while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }
       bre.close();
       p.waitFor();
       System.out.println("Done.");
     }
     catch (Exception err) {
       err.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run a shell which runs multiple commands.

e.g.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh", "-c", 
          "iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p iscsiInfo.ipAddress &&"
          +" ls /var/lib/iscsi/nodes");
```

If you use ProcessBuilder you can redirect the error to the standard output and have one stream to read.

Comment: at least in java 8: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", 
          "iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p iscsiInfo.ipAddress &&"
          +" ls /var/lib/iscsi/nodes"})`